# Get name of primary field of Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django, every model has a pseudo attribute `pk`, that points to the field that is declared as primary key.

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    payload = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
```

In this model, the `pk` attribute would point to the implicit `id` field, that is generated if no field is declared to be the primary.

```
class CustomPK(models.Model)
    primary = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary=True)
    payload = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
```

In this model, the `pk` attribute would point to the explicit defined primary key field `primary`

So my question is, how can I get the name of the field, that is the primary key?

Comment: Why do you need it? `pk` can be used in every circumstance.

Comment: We need this for migrating one database to another via script.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, so wrong! `pk` is just a shortcut to `AutoField` named `id`, referring to a column, which could even not be there! Just stumbled into `filter` throwing `OperationalError` because there is no `id` column in the table.

Comment: @ogurets is incorrect. `pk` is an alias to _whatever_ field is the primary key of the model, regardless of what kind of field it is, or what it's named.

Comment: @coredumperror yep, I messed up - looked at `Model._get_pk_val` for confirmation.

Comment: @ogurets: good for you for clarifying. Many people would continue to argue their point or not clarify after realizing an error.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You will also have an attribute "name" on the pk-attribute. This seems to hold the name of the Field.

```
CustomPK._meta.pk.name
```

In my case I get the value "id" as result (like it should). :-)

Comment: pk.name does not return column name, it skips "_id" postfix. (tested on django 1.7 )  i have used CustomPK._meta.pk.column

Answer (score 6):

[Field](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L90) objects have a `primary_key` attribute

```
for field in CustomPK._meta.fields:
  print field.primary_key
  print field.name


# True
# primary
# False
# payload
```